# Cómo hacer Comando para ver video y ejecutar un .exe?

Tags: cmd

Como hacer para que se ejecute completamente un video, al finalizar debe ejecutarse un .exe, he intentado con

```
@echo off
start vlc.exe C:\Users\Admon\Desktop\carpeta\VideoIntro.mp4
timeout /t 80> NUL
start C:\Intro\intro.exe
exit
```

pero no me responde adecuadamente, ya que intro.exe solamente debe cerrarlo el usuario